# Deserialize json string to non public class members

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have class object like this:

```
 public class CustomerCollection
        {
            public CustomerOrder CustOrder;
    
            public CustomerCollection();
            public CustomerCollection(CustomerItem[] custItems);
        }



public class CustomerItem: IComparable
    {
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public string NoteType { get; set; }
        public int NoteTypeID { get; set; }
        public int RecordID { get; set; }}
   }
```

I am unable to deserialize my json as shown below to the CustomerItem class properties

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "Server.CustomerCollection,Server.Common",
    "custItems": {
        "$id": "2",
        "$type": "Server.CustomerItem[],Server.Common",
        "$values": [
            {
                "$id": "3",
                "$type": "Server.CustomerItem,Server.Common",
                "note": "test note",
                "NoteType ": "Test note type",   
                "NoteTypeID ": 123,     
                "RecordId ": 15678,
            }
        ]
    },
    "CustOrder": 0
}
```

This my how I am deserializing:

```
retObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerCollection>(response, Customer.GetDefualtSettings());
```

Only the custOrder gets the mapping done. CustomerItem properties are not mapping : actually CustomerItem[] array is empty.

Can someone give direction of the constructor handling here?

Comment: your json is the wrong shape you need to make sure the shape of the string matches the shape of the object your seserializing to, so make a type which is the same shape of the JSON and desrialize at that.

Comment: Run your JSON through converters like:- https://json2csharp.com/json-to-csharp
If you dont see class structure matching what you have. Chances are you need to re-do class design.